# JavaFX: как представить файлы и папки файловой системы

Tags: java, javafx

С помощью какого элемента управления в JavaFX лучше реализовать переходы по папкам и файлам?

Comment: Что значит "реализовать переходы по папкам и файлам"? Для отображения списка файлов и папок можно использовать `TableView` или `TreeTableView`, переход по одинарному или двойному клику например. Не понятно к чему кнопки в заголовке вопроса.

Comment: А их и немного. 'TableView' and 'TreeTableView'

Comment: на счет кнопок, хотел поменять заголовок, но так и не дошел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TreeView<String>` отлично подойдет. FXML скрипт типа:

```
<TreeView fx:id="foldersTreeView" />
```

Заполняем его списком каталогов и файлов:

```
public TreeItem<String> getNodesForDirectory(File directory) {
   TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<String>(directory.getName());
        for(File f : directory.listFiles()) {
            if(f.isDirectory()) //если каталог идем на рекурсию
                root.getChildren().add(getNodesForDirectory(f));
            else //если просто файл заполняем только имя
                root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>(f.getName()));
        }
        return root;
    }
```

Вызываем примерно так:

```
TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<String>();
treeView.setRoot(getNodesForDirectory(new File("//")); //yначинаем с корня
```

Comment: использовал его для представления отдельного дерева каталогов. Позже скину код, может кому понадобиться.